# Dialog has two scrollbar, but I want one

Tags: css, angular, dialog, scrollbar

I made a dialog and gave it a fixed height. I'd like to keep this height, but I have two scroll bars and only one to keep scrolling through.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade dialog-layout-modal-body" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" #modal>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content dialog-layout-modal-body">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Add new item</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .dialog-layout-modal-body {
      overflow-y: auto;
      max-height: 662px;
    }
}
```

[image]

How do I solve the problem of leaving only one scrollbar but also keep the height of the dialog?

Comment: You can try adding overflow: hidden on element with unwanted scroll.

Comment: This solution did not solve my problem @maciejze

Answer (score 0):

If your `body` element gets a class called `modal-open` when the model shows then use the below css to hide the `body`'s scrollbar.

```
body.modal-open {
   height: 100vh;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

`100vh` makes the body's height 100% of the viewport. More details at [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/prevent-page-scrolling-when-a-modal-is-open/).

Comment: Isn't it very clear, then, should I give this class to the modal now? @Dumisani

Comment: I'm using bootstrap @Dumisani

Comment: Oh nevermind, I've just realised in your image your body element gets the class `modal-open` so the code should work for you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, the error still persists @Dumisani

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something where I can see your full html and css?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wimomapowo/edit?html,css,output Hope the code is understandable @Dumisani